# Rspec/Capybara - how to target data-target attribute inside a span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

in my Rails4/rspec app, I need to male Capybara click on a zone that has no formal "link"  , using data-target attribute.

html

```
<div class="info-zone">
   <span data-target="#myInfoZone1" class="City" data-toggle="modal">  
   </span>
</div>
```

My current attempt at using capyabar fails

```
describe "modal loads with the right content" do
      it "has right text" do
        visit actual_page_path(:id => @deal.id) 
        find("span[data-target='#myInfoZone1']").click
      end
```

I currently get this error

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "span[data-target='#myInfoZone1']"
```

How can I make capybara "find" and click on the  zone ?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I found out why capybara is not finding it!

for a reason I can't  understand, that is the html output code capybara finds

```
<!-- city zone -->
<div id="city-zone">

  <!--
    We gather here the various types of <spans> and load it via javascript
we append it to the the div id=city-zone
  -->
</div>
```

I am using javascript to load inside this div. so when I load the 'page source' i see what's above

but when I go on chrome dev tools, then I see:

```
<!-- city zone -->
<div id="city-zone">

   <div class="info-zone">
       <!--
    We gather here the various types of <spans> and load it via javascript
we append it to the the div id=city-zone
  -->
   <span data-target="#myInfoZone1" class="City" data-toggle="modal">  
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i guess capybara sees the same thing as I see when I load the page source: no .
how come my javascript which I append does not appear in the html code source?

what to do about it to make capybara work

Comment: Capybara's find should work accordingly!
I have simulated the same scenario and it seems to work just fine.

I'm guessing there is something else wrong with your scenario and/or view.

Make sure you're visiting the correct show view, or even better try to actually visit the path on your actual browser and view source to make sure you're targeting the correct selector.

Comment: it's really weird. i have used save_and_open_page which loads the page as capybara sees it, and I do see the span element and <span data-target="#myInfoZone1" class="City" data-toggle="modal">  . So the view is the right one but capybara still says it can't see it on the test.

Comment: @moeabdol i edited my question.

Comment: I guess since you're using save_and_open_page that your are using capybara-webkit. Right? if that was the case then make sure your feature is javascript enabled as such: Rspec.feature "test something", js: true do

Comment: will try but i think it won't work. even on my real page ( no test here) when i load the page source there is not the < span>. only when i look with chrome dev tools inspector i see it. it must be because i append this html block via a js file.

Comment: capybara-webkit is your answer to any javascript integration tests. If your scenarios has front-end javascript operations that loads on your page-load, then you have to enable javascript in your tests. Installing capybara-webkit is easy. Include the gem in your gemfile, add Capybara.javascript_driver= :webkit to your rails_helper.rb file, and in your feature RSpec.feature "your feature to test", js: true do, and it should work. You can also check the section "Running specs with Javascript" here https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications

Comment: Also let me know what is the console output when you load the page on your browser. If nothing shows then it might be a turbolinks issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any javascript errors being thrown in the console?  In dev mode your JS assets are loaded as separate files which means that an error in one doesn't stop the other files code from being run.  In test mode the assets are usually concatenated together into one JS file, which means that an error occurring in one can stop code in the others from being run resulting in things not being loaded.

Comment: will check both your comments tomorrow, thanks

Comment: @moeabdol yes i had capyabar-webkit, but I had not put :js=>true in my test block .you're the man! please answer the question with a real formal answer below so I can attribute you the question and the points:)

Comment: thanks both for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara's default driver only tests html rendered by your back-end application server. If you want to test pages with front-end javascript as well, you should use a javascript-enabled driver with Capybara.

Luckily, the folks at [thoughtbot](https://thoughtbot.com/) made a Capybara extension just for that [Capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) You can easily install it in your Gemfile. Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#usage) on how to install the gem.

Finally, once you install it, you can enable javascript tests in your feature specs by adding **js: true** in your **features/scenarios** as following:

```
RSpec.feature "test my new feature", js: true do
  # my test
end
```

Comment: i have a pb though, quite tricky: if i don't put js=> true, capybara does not find the span ( as it's brought to the html through a js file with .append) but if i use js=> true capybara finds the span BUT , as i have witnessed by loading the test view by save_and_open_page, it doubles the nb of span. it is most likely due to a well known pb of turblinks firing twice the js. my pb is that it does not do it in my normal app ( i checked) but only double fire in the rspec/capybara tests. how to avoid this in tests ? i have jquery-turbolinks but on tests still fire twice the js.

Comment: Have you double checked if all your javascript runs inside a $("document").ready(function(){ // your javascript here });

Comment: i'll check tomorrow but in order not to have double events firing in the real app, i had already removed the document.ready but inside tests it s still double firing. it's weird the actual view is allright but not the rsoec capybara save_and_open_page. i'll double though tomorrow. tx for your help

Comment: I don't have any document(ready), just using Paloma gem but i don't think it's related.

Comment: I think it my be my use of gon gem doing this. tx anyway, I'll investigate.